# google maps - kml file not displayed properly

Tags: maps, kml

Depending on how I load a KML file in Google Maps, it gives different results!

First, here is the link to the KML file: http://www.hibiscus.cc/KML/Trace-2010-2011.kml

1 - All is OK when I create a new map in Google Maps and use the "import" function to import the URL

2 - But when I enter directly the URL: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://www.hibiscus.cc/KML/Trace-2010-2011.kml
the track gets shifted about 2000 km north-west (1300 miles)

This is an issue for me as I intend to embed the map in a blog, use NetworkLinks to show tracks for different years and dynamically update the current year track.

Not sure what else I could send, but I stand ready to send more details as needed.
Thank you for any thought on how to fix or get around.
P.

Comment: I am not sure what "projections" means - The routes are exactly the same shape, but when I use method "2" it is entirely shifted to the NW.  So if you do not see a shift of the "route" between the 2 methods, would it mean that the issue is on my client side?  I use firefox

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with Internet Explorer and method "2" displays the path correctly.

Just for reference, here is the path displayed in Firefox (20.0.1):
[sorry but the system does not allow me to post images!]

And now this is the same with Internet Explorer:[sorry but the system does not allow me to post images!]

So I guess it has to do with the setup of Firefox on my machine

Thank you for your time

Philippe